# Swift: Use of undeclared type 'ViewController'

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have created a `StoryboardManager` object that will manage all the storyboards and all the ViewController IDs in one place. I am getting an error on the second getter method for `OnboardingOne`, which is:

> Use of undeclared type "OnboardingOne"

The code for the `StoryboardManager` object is:

```
class StoryboardManager: NSObject {

    class func login() -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
    }

    class func CameraView() -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "CameraView", bundle: nil)
    }

    class func OnboardingOne() -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "OnboardingOne", bundle: nil)
    }

    class func MainView() -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "MainView", bundle: nil)
    }

    // MARK: viewController getter methods
    class func loginViewController() -> Login {
        return login().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login") as! Login
    } // NO ERRORS

    class func OnboardingViewController() -> OnboardingOne {
        return OnboardingOne().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingOne") as! OnboardingOne
    } //ERROR: Use of undeclared type "OnboardingOne"

}
```

I have no idea what this means or how to get around it so any information would be helpful.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It means what it says.  You have declared a function to return something of type OnboardingOne:

```
  class func OnboardingViewController() -> OnboardingOne { // <<-- here
    return OnboardingOne().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingOne") as! OnboardingOne
 }
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
class func OnboardingViewController() -> ViewController { ...
```

Comment: Thanks. OnboardingOne is a class. As is Login in the method above, although Login brings no error. So I don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: I don't see you defining OnboardingOne as a class anywhere in the code you've posted. Instead you define it as a class function.